# Biblatex disable autopunct for autocite once

Tags: biblatex

I use the `\autocite` command with the `autocite=footnote` option for citations. If I use this command to cite a word which is directly followed by a punctuation (most often a comma or period) the superscript is moved to the right of the punctuation.

Consider the following cases:

```
This is the main sentence with an important word\autocite[][]{ABC12}, followed by a subordinate clause.
This is the main sentence with an important word\autocite[][]{ABC12}.
```

will lead to

> This is the main sentence with an important word,² followed by a subordinate clause.
>
> This is the main sentence with an important word.³

In general the option `autopunct` which is responsible for this behavior is useful (for example at the end of a sentence when the citation is for the complete sentence). However in the cases described above or in some similar cases it would be useful to disable the `autopunct` option temporary only for this time.

Has one of you an idea how to achieve a command like `\autociteAP` and `\autocitesAP` (for an autocite command with a disabled autopunct option) or how to give a parameter `noautopunct` to the normal `\autocite(s)` command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest thing is just to add an empty pair of braces after the command and before the punctuation:

```
\autocite[][]{bertram}{},
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

This is the main sentence with an important word\autocite[][]{bertram}{},
followed by a subordinate clause.  This is the main sentence with an
important word\autocite[][]{bertram}{}.

This is the main sentence with an important word\autocite[][]{bertram},
followed by a subordinate clause.  This is the main sentence with an
important word\autocite[][]{bertram}.


\end{document}
```